# Thunkable JSON POST

Tags: thunkable

I'm trying to post some data with Thunkable. It works but it seems like it's sending as text not in JSON, regardless of headers. How do I know? My python Flask code is showing None instead of JSON content. It works just fine when sending the same JSON string from Postman.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks
Pavol

[image: Thunkable]

Answer (score 0):

Use variables to capture data from inputs then buttons to execute post

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar. Usually, the issue is is that the Python backend is unable to interpret your link OR you need to import the `json` library to your Python to interpret the "text".

Without further information, however, I won't be able to assess why that is the case.

Happy coding!